# Prevent div from showing after slideUp() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a small piece of code, so when I click on the question mark, it shows another `div`. However, when I click on the `body`, it should hide the just revealed `div`.

The problem I am running into, is that even though I use `.slideUp()` when the person clicks on the `body` (note: the `body` is only clickable on the height of the `?`), it also shows after clicking on the `body` again. How do I make it so clicking on `body` won't show the `.popover` again? If I add `.hide()` after `.slideUp()`, it just hides it directly and the `slideUp` effect is gone.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rnbkC)

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
  <span class="qs">? <span class="popover above">Voeg toe aan wensenlijst</span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #e3fbff;
}
/* Just to center things */
.center {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 30px;
}

/* The element to click on */
.qs {
  background-color: #02bdda;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #e3fbff;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;

  .popover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 42px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    display:none;
    font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
    left: -95px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 4;
  }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".qs").click(function(){
  $(".popover ").slideToggle();
});

$('body').click(function() {
    // Hide all hidden content
    $('.popover').slideUp();
});

$('.popover').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation() });

$('.qs').click(function(e) {
    // this stops the event from then being caught by the body click binding
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: One way is to add a `is:visible` clause inside body's click event to check the showen/hidden property of popover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the tooltip when clicking, if it is visible.
You don't need more code than this:

```
var popover = $('.popover');
var qs = $('.qs');

qs.click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  popover.slideToggle();
});

$('html').click(function() {
   if(popover.is(':visible')) {
     popover.slideUp();
   }
});

$('.popover').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation() });
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/JimmyRare/pen/Fuovf)

Comment: Accepted your answer, as it makes the code a lot shorter. And it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `.popover` is visible like:

```
$('body').click(function() {
  // Hide all hidden content
  if($('.popover').is(":visible"))
    $('.popover').slideUp();
});
```

Also you don't need to use `slideup()` and `hide()` together.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzqAa)

Comment: Muchos gracias! This was exactly what I needed. Will accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: Oh and I know I don't need to use them together, but I thought that could maybe have been the solution for the problem, just to show what I've tried :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the popup is not click on you can do a check like this

```
 var mouse_is_inside = false;

 $('.popover').hover(function() {
        mouse_is_inside=true;
 }, function() {
        mouse_is_inside=false;
 });

 $("body").live('mouseup', function() {
       if(! mouse_is_inside)
           $('.popover').slideUp();
 });
```